# hamburger menu issue and logo issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some minor bootstrap issues i cannot seem to solve.

1. I want the logo and the text that appears on the right of it to simply appear on the left instead of the center. (I have tried pull-left with no luck)
2. I want the hamburger menu to appear on the far right, after i added the visible-sm-block and visible-lg-block to the nav-bar toggle it appears in the center. I added it because it was not displaying on mobile screens??? and i need it to display on tablet and small devices only. I have tried pull-right

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <img alt="Logo" class="brnd" src="" height="30" /><span class="brnd2">| Specialty FORCES  </span>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle  visible-sm-block visible-xs-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                   
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="">1</a></li>
                        <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">4</a></li>
                        <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">5</a></li>
                         <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: will you pls elaborate your issue? what you want and what you don't want on desktop and mobile device? at point number 1 you are saying "I want the logo and the text that appears on the right of it to simply appear on the left instead of the center." you mean extreme left? and bdw its not in center. please tell us what you want and what you don't want briefly

Comment: hi, i want the logo and text to appear on the extreme left. on all screens I want the hamburger menu to appear to the far right on tablet, small, and extra small screens only. (nothing menu related to appear in desktop mode).

Comment: logo and that text can be fixed but showing menu at right on small devices is a bad idea it should be collapsible on small devices, this is what responsiveness means, what if i use very small screen size phones your menu will break into pieces

Comment: anyways i'm writing the answer hope it will help you

Comment: i dont want the menu to show right on small device. I want the menu icon to display right on small device (yes collapsible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{padding-right: 70px;}
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle{position: absolute;right: 0;}
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0; 
      float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


             <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#jb-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                      <div>
                      <div class="navbar-header">
                  
                </div>
                  <a class="pull-left navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <span><img alt="Logo" class="brnd" src="" height="30" /></span>
                       |Specialty FORCES
                    </a>
                      
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="jb-navbar-collapse">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-fix">
           <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">1</a></li>
           <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">2</a></li>
           <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">3</a></li>
           <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">4</a></li>
           <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">5</a></li>
           <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="#">6</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
```

hope this resolve your issue

Comment: hi, when i test your code in the chrome simulator, the hamburger menu does not appear?

Comment: check resolution we are hiding for large devices

Comment: yes i know but in chrome when i select device type (iphone 4,5,6) or tablet the hamburger menu never shows

Comment: check your meta tag viewport it should be <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"> will do a trick

Comment: that works for all exept the two tablets (ipad mini and ipad)

Comment: It doesn't appear because the iPads screen is too big. You have the hamburger icon appear only on 767px and below. if you really want to achieve it then we need to remove hidden-sm or we need to change navbar breakpoints which one you prefer?

Comment: i tried removing hidden-sm. I dont want the text at the top at all. So maybe we can change the breakpoint

Comment: well appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143530/discussion-between-vzupo-and-this-girish).